# Why does the error show when strapi start in strapi

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, strapi

Why does stop  strapi after create realation between tables and  become  the error show when strapi start in strapi

```
   (node:1264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table `tmp_posts` already exists
    at Client_SQLite3._query (F:\angular7\Server\BlogApi\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js:108:12)
    at Client_SQLite3.query (F:\angular7\Server\BlogApi\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:192:17)
    at Runner.<anonymous> (F:\angular7\Server\BlogApi\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:138:36)
From previous event:
    at F:\angular7\Server\BlogApi\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:47:21
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:121:23)
From previous event:
    at Runner.run (F:\angular7\Server\BlogApi\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:33:30)
    at Raw.Target.then (F:\angular7\Server\BlogApi\node_modules\knex\lib\interface.js:23:43)
(node:1264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1264) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[2019-02-28T06:28:21.235Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2019-02-28T06:28:21.247Z] error (hook:bookshelf) takes too long to load
(hook:bookshelf) takes too long to load
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of console output, copy it and paste into your question as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, I got the `` SQLITE_ERROR: table `xyz` already exists `` when I renamed the Type. Try to revert it to the initial name or delete it and re-create it from the content manager.